# Issue using the ms-hidden classes of office-ui-fabric

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

I am using office-ui-fabric-react (v7.22.1) to style my application with a grid layout. For my mobile styling i use the ms-hidden classes to show/hide stuff on different resolutions.

Basically I have 2 divs:

- div class="ms-hiddenLgDown" --> expected to be hidden up to a
  resolution of 1024px.
- div class="ms-hiddenXlUp --> expected to be
  hidden for a resolution higher then or equal to 1024px.

It seems to be working except for a screen width of exactly 1024px. In this case both of them are hidden. I checked the fabric styles and found the following:

- ms-hiddenLgDown has a 'display: none' for resolution 0 - 1023,99999
- ms-hiddenXlUp has a 'display: none' for resolution 1024 - ....

I would expect for a resolution of exactly 1024 the ms-hiddenXlUp should be active and the ms-hiddenLgDown should not be active.
What i see is that both classes are active effectively hiding both divs.

I am using chrome for testing.

Below code shows my html mark-up:

```
<header> 
  <div class="ms-HiddenLgDown">
    <div class="ms-Grid">
        <div class="ms-GridRow">
            ...      
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ms-HiddenXlUp">
    <div class="ms-Grid">
        <div class="ms-GridRow>
            ...      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post all your relevant code here so we can reproduce your problem. On another hand, what stops you from adjusting the mediaqueries?

Comment: I Added the html markup. The media queries are added to the styles of office-ui-fabric-react. Ik can add extra media queries to catch the specific case of 1024px but I was wondering why it is not catched in the office-ui-fabric-react styles

Comment: Hey Robin, i don't think this will happen. you need to read [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/web/layout).